# Is a gradual increase in the reported GPU temperature a sign of impending hardware failure?

Tags: graphics-card, temperature, overheating, flash-player

It's an uber old computer

**OS**: Win 7 Pro

**M/B**: P7P55 DE

**GPU**: NVidia GEForce 8400 GS

**Cabinet**: Antec with a single 120mm fan set at high-speed

**Security**: MS Security Essentials

**Problem:**

ASUS SmartDoctor politely pops up to warn me the VGA card has overheated. The reported temperature has increased gradually from 60C to 65C. Ambient temperature is in the 40C range. (The GPU is set-up to warn me when the temperature exceeds 48C - this never occurred in the billions of aeons I've possessed this computer ... until now!)

I do not run games. This first occurred when I visited facebook after a hiatus (ugh! Flash!) web-sites. By default the browser is set-up **to ask** when it encounters flash/multi-media content in a web-site. This also happens when I attempt to read documents from the scanner, or from a PDF with scanned content in them.

My take is this is either a hard-ware fault, some kind of driver issues at work, or spy-ware.

MSE reports all is well. I suspect I may be looking at a catastrophic hard-ware fault in the GPU someplace in the near future - or a problem with the latest Flash player.

Is a gradual increase in the reported GPU temperature a sign of impending hardware failure?

Comment: have you checked for dust in the heatsinks, fans and grilles?

Comment: I haven't. Good point.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. It's a sign that web sites have become more and more GPU intensive over time.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/518740)

Comment: @Heptite The question was "Is a gradual increase in the reported GPU temperature a sign of impending hardware failure?" and the answer is no. I'm not critiquing anything or requesting clarification, I'm answering the question he asked.

Comment: Forgive me if this appears to be a rhetoric - it isn't. If it was only a matter of GPU intensive sites - surely the problem would be more widely reported?

Comment: @Everyone What problem are you talking about? The question didn't report any problem -- you configured your system to warn you if your GPU hit perfectly normal operating temperatures, and it did. It's widely reported that systems appear to get slower and run hotter over time even though they're only used for "normal web browsing" because what we consider to be normal web browsing has changed dramatically over time.